# How to reject user from subscribing or unsubscribe a user from server side with spring stomp websocket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am trying to force unsubscribe a user when he is banned by the admin and block that user from subscribing when he is banned. The ban status is saved inside my db. I currently have an interceptor to do the blocking at `preSend` but the connection is closed when I throw an exception. Is there anyway to reject a subscribe message without closing the socket connection?

```
 @Override
  public Message<?> preSend(@NonNull Message<?> message, @NonNull MessageChannel channel) {
    StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
    if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE.equals(headerAccessor.getCommand())) {
      checkIsBanned(headerAccessor.getDestination(), headerAccessor.getUser());
    }
    return message;
  }

  private void checkIsBanned(String destination, Principal principal) {
    if (destination == null || !destination.matches(CHAT_TOPIC_REGEX)) {
      return;
    }
    String errorMessage = resourceBundle.getMessage("err.channel.banned");
    if (!(principal instanceof OAuth2Authentication) || !(((OAuth2Authentication) principal).getPrincipal() instanceof SUserDetails)) {
      throw new MessagingException(errorMessage);
    }
    String channelId = destination.split("/")[3];
    Long profileId = getProfileId(principal);
    if (profileId == null) {
      throw new MessagingException(errorMessage);
    }
    channelUserRepo.findByChannelIdAndUserId(channelId, profileId).filter(ChannelUser::isBanned).orElseThrow(() -> new MessagingException(errorMessage));
  }

  private Long getProfileId(Principal principal) {
    return ((SUserDetails) ((OAuth2Authentication) principal).getPrincipal()).getProfileId();
  }
```

I also try to force unsubscribe when admin ban the user by getting the user from `userRegistry` and remove his subscription but that didnt work. Is there any way to do this as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to reject the subscription by just return null in `preSend` it will ignore the subscription message instead of throwing error. You can also notify the user by sending a notification through socket to the user.

```
public ChatInterceptor(ResourceBundle resourceBundle, ChannelUserRepository channelUserRepo, @Lazy SimpMessagingTemplate socket) {
    this.resourceBundle = resourceBundle;
    this.channelUserRepo = channelUserRepo;
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  @Override
  public Message<?> preSend(@NonNull Message<?> message, @NonNull MessageChannel channel) {
    StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
    if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE.equals(headerAccessor.getCommand())) {
      if (checkIsBanned(headerAccessor.getDestination(), headerAccessor.getUser())) {
        socket.convertAndSendToUser(getSocketUsername(headerAccessor.getUser()), ServicePath.NOTIFICATION,
            new SocketResponse(resourceBundle.getMessage("err.channel.banned"), ERROR));
        return null;
      }
    }
    return message;
  }
```